# Writing an HTML table to Excel using Selenium & openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, selenium-webdriver, openpyxl

I'm having some trouble getting this loop to write to Excel in a clean matrix.

The idea is to iterate through the row an HTML table & essentially recreate it in Excel.

The block relevant to this issue looks like this:

```
#Creates new WB & names the active sheet
wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = "Escalation Table"

#finds the escalation table, then iterates through & writes it to the Active Excel Sheet
esc_table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody")

for row in esc_table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"tr"):
    cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"td")
    for cell in cells:
        sheet.cell(row = 1+sheet.max_row, column= 1+cells.index(cell)).value = cell.text
```

[Currently, my output looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IjJX.png)

I know my issue is arising in the last line, specifically the definition of row w/in sheet.cell().

I also tried changing this to match the column argument i.e.

```
sheet.cell(row=1+cells.index(cell),column = 1+cells.index(cell)).value = cell.text
```

However, that just ended up overwriting each previous  leaving me w/ only the last record.

Comment: Just use `ws.append()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to use a stable count for row;
Currently you have it increasing on the 'td' loop where each cell should be on the same row;

```
row = 1+sheet.max_row
```

Here you're writing to a new row which increases the `max_row` value so that on the next loop `max_row` is one larger and the next 'td' value is written in the next column one row down and so on.

The row needs to change once on the 'tr' tag so you could use enumerate for a second count (here called `row_num`) starting at row 2 on the 'tr' loop.

```
for row_num, row in enumerate(esc_table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr"),2):
    cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
    for cell in cells:
        sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=1 + cells.index(cell)).value = cell.text
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson, moken! Enumerate works perfects for my needs.

Comment: It's nearly always best to avoid any kind of counter in this kind of loop. `ws.append()` handles all that and creating a list for it makes things clearer.

Comment: @charlieclark is your thought process for avoiding the counter related to handling tables of varying sizes? If not, mind providing some insight into your reasoning?